# Django cant find pip3 installed module

Tags: python, django, pip

I created a Python module and installed it using pip3. If i check on dist-package folder its there. If i import this module into a new Python project its ok.
Problem: I would like to use this module on my Django project, but when i try to import it can't be found.

Already tried: If i copy the module to site-package, it works but i don't get why i have to do this. I would like that this Python module installed with pip3 is visible for everyone without the need to copy/paste from dist folder.

Comment: Possibly https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41535915/python-pip-install-from-local-dir

Answer (score 0):

Whatever the package you installed using pip3, those packages mapped to python3 version, and also will be installed in /usr/lib/python3.x/site-packages/

for your reference, [What's the difference between dist-packages and site-packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9387928/whats-the-difference-between-dist-packages-and-site-packages)

Comment: o looked at this location and there isn't any packages there. Another problem is that my django project seems to look for package at ~/.local/lib/python3.x/site-packages/
My Django project looks at dist-packages too but dont get the module if it isn't on site-package