# Make bar chart race in python stay on the last frame longer

Tags: python

Hi I'm using bar chart race in python and I need it to stay on the last frame for a bit longer. It just ends very abruptly and you don't get a chance to see the final table.

here is my code:

```
import bar_chart_race as bcr
bcr.bar_chart_race(df = df_tp, 
                   n_bars = 10, 
                   sort='desc',
                   period_fmt='Gameweek {x:.0f}',
                   period_length=1500,
                   steps_per_period = steps_per_period,
                   title='my title',
                   filename = 'fpl_fitcip.mp4',
                   interpolate_period = 'false'
                   )
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem to be documented anywhere, but looking a the [source](https://github.com/dexplo/bar_chart_race/blob/master/bar_chart_race/_bar_chart_race.py), there's a parameter named `end_period_pause`. Supply an integer for the number of frames to pause on the last data period.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work it gives me this error: TypeError: bar_chart_race() got an unexpected keyword argument 'end_period_pause'.

Comment: Hm. How did you install bar_chart_race? If from pip, it's possible you have an older version than what's in the repo.

Comment: No from conda, but I can try to update it

Comment: this is the right answer but if you got an unexpected keyword argument 'end_period_pause', then you need pip install bar_chart_race --upgrade.. but unfotunately it didn't work when i tried it.. so i downloaded the source code in github.. https://github.com/dexplo/bar_chart_race/blob/master/bar_chart_race/_bar_chart_race.py and replaced the bar_chart_race folder in the site-packages folder with the bar_chart_race folder from the downloaded source code. You can try this to find where bar_chart_race folder is:  import bar_chart_race; print(bar_chart_race.__file__)

Comment: @glenmark Rather than copying over your existing pip installation or otherwise installing things manually, it might be easier/tidier to use pip and install [from source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41535915/python-pip-install-from-local-dir) or even [directly from the Github repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8247605/configuring-so-that-pip-install-can-work-from-github) (without needing to separately download it yourself first), but in the end, whatever works.